# XSLT - stop from processing a block of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, docx

I am using an xslt to generate `.docx` files

The xslt file contains ms xml and my xsl code

The problem I am  having is with this block

```
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="008C5EB7" w:rsidSect="008C5EB7">
    <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>                   
    <w:pgSz w:w="16834" w:h="11904" w:orient="landscape"/>
    <w:pgMar w:top="1304" w:right="851" w:bottom="1474" w:left="851" 
             w:header="567" w:footer="624" w:gutter="0"/>
    <w:pgBorders>
      <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="24" w:space="0" w:color="948A54"  
                w:themeColor="background2" w:themeShade="80"/>
    </w:pgBorders>
    <w:cols w:space="708"/>
    <w:printerSettings r:id="rId7"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

The `r:id` tag gets changed to `id` by xsl

Any ideas how to stop this ?

Thanks, Alex

**XML**

```
<list>
<institution title="UNKNOWN">
    <candidate>
        <name>Alex+Handley</name>
        <history>
            <job_title>Credit+Analyst+</job_title>
            <institution>A+shop</institution>
        </history>
    </candidate>
</institution>
```

**XSLT**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <w:document xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
                <w:body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="list/institution">
                    <w:tbl>
                        <w:tblPr>
                            <w:tblW w:w="15168" w:type="dxa"/>
                            <w:tblInd w:w="108" w:type="dxa"/>
                            <w:tblBorders>
                                <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
                                <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
                                <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
                                <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
                            </w:tblBorders>
                            <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="4F5C62"/>
                            <w:tblLook w:val="00BF"/>
                        </w:tblPr>
                        <w:tblGrid>
                            <w:gridCol w:w="15168"/>
                        </w:tblGrid>
                        <w:tr w:rsidR="008C5EB7">
                            <w:trPr>
                                <w:trHeight w:val="567"/>
                            </w:trPr>
                            <w:tc>
                                <w:tcPr>
                                    <w:tcW w:w="15168" w:type="dxa"/>
                                    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="4F5C62"/>
                                    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                                </w:tcPr>
                                <w:p w:rsidR="008C5EB7" w:rsidRPr="006F6210" w:rsidRDefault="008C5EB7" w:rsidP="008C5EB7">
                                    <w:pPr>
                                        <w:rPr>
                                            <w:b/>
                                            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                                        </w:rPr>
                                    </w:pPr>
                                    <w:r>
                                        <w:rPr>
                                            <w:b/>
                                            <w:bCs/>
                                            <w:caps/>
                                            <w:noProof/>
                                        </w:rPr>
                                        <w:t>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                                        </w:t>
                                    </w:r>
                                </w:p>
                            </w:tc>
                        </w:tr>
                    </w:tbl>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                        <w:p w:rsidR="008C5EB7" w:rsidRDefault="008C5EB7" w:rsidP="008C5EB7">
                            <w:pPr>
                                <w:spacing w:line="20" w:lineRule="exact"/>
                            </w:pPr>
                        </w:p>
                        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="008C5EB7" w:rsidSect="008C5EB7">
                            <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>
                            <w:pgSz w:w="16834" w:h="11904" w:orient="landscape"/>
                            <w:pgMar w:top="1304" w:right="851" w:bottom="1474" w:left="851" w:header="567" w:footer="624" w:gutter="0"/>
                            <w:pgBorders>
                                <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="24" w:space="0" w:color="948A54" w:themeColor="background2" w:themeShade="80"/>
                            </w:pgBorders>
                            <w:cols w:space="708"/>
                            <w:printerSettings r:id="rId7"/>
                        </w:sectPr>
                </w:body>
            </w:document>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Because you haven't provided either the source XML document or the XSLT transformation, then the next possible reason can be the bad weather.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the weather is amazing today.. but I have added the xml/xslt

Comment: Yes, amazing, but too cold :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cant't repro**, the result contains the `r:id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ill check over the rest of my code and look for bugs.

Comment: Fixed the error but not sure what the problem was yet. Will work it out and post the answer :)

Comment: @Alex: The problem disappeared as result of weather improving :)